# Window 8 : RAM usage (committed memory)

Tags: windows-8, memory, task-manager

[image: Memory usage]

I have a 4 GB RAM memory.
In task manager you can see tha **Committed** memory is 5,6/7,9 GB RAM.
Why that if **In use** memory is just 3,1 GB ?
Is Windows using the Page File ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are these different kinds of memory usage in Windows 7 task manager?](http://superuser.com/questions/359295/what-are-these-different-kinds-of-memory-usage-in-windows-7-task-manager), also see: [Commit charge is 100% full but physical memory is just 60% when using no page file](http://superuser.com/questions/482678/commit-charge-is-100-full-but-physical-memory-is-just-60-when-using-no-page-fi), and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_charge

Comment: Yes, my bad. They are similar. I will leave mine too because it's related to Windows 8 and has a more recent screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to TechNet's introduction to new `taskmgr`:

> Committed virtual memory is private, nonshareable virtual memory created by processes or the OS or drives that MAY need to be paged out. This always starts out in RAM and *may* get paged out if necessary.  So committed memory can be backed by RAM (and if you have no paging file, it remains in RAM until the VM is deleted such as at process exit).

Source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/08/09/task-manager-in-windows-server-2012-and-windows-8.aspx

So.. yes, Windows is using page file if present but in general it reserves some space in memory - like mentioned above - just in case. However, this commited memory won't necessary be paged out.

Comment: I wish to caution that the term "reserved" should not be used in this context. "Reserved memory" in Windows is another type of virtual address space allocation that takes no space in either RAM or the pagefile.

Comment: Of the two "committed" numbers, the first is the amount in use, the second is the limit (which is simply RAM size + current pagefile size). Note that even though the current value is 5.6 GB and you only have 4 GB RAM, that doesn't mean that there's 1.6 GB in the pagefile! Some or most of that may have been allocated (in terms of virtual address space allocation) but never accessed yet. In that case it doesn't take RAM *or* pagefile space. The first time it's accessed, though, it will be manifested in RAM (as the TechNet article stated). This happens on a page-at-a-time basis.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'll change that to `commited` as there's definitely a difference.