# RAM lost during upgrade from Windows XP - Windows 10

Tags: windows-xp, windows-10, memory

I have recently upgraded from Windows XP to Windows 10. In Windows XP, I had 3.97 GB of RAM according to the Windows XP task manager. Now, I have only 2 GB according to the Windows 10 task manager. The following are other things my task manager says about my RAM.

- Hardware Reserved - 0.7 MB;
- Committed - 2.1/9.9 GB.

I have 4 GB in RAM sticks installed in my computer.

Comment: Read those links. The memory is not lost, Windows 10 just displays the information in a different way than XP. If it still doesn't make sense, post a comment. 
http://superuser.com/questions/836286/window-8-ram-usage-committed-memory 
http://superuser.com/questions/482678/commit-charge-is-100-full-but-physical-memory-is-just-60-when-using-no-page-fi

Comment: post pictures of taskmgr->Perf->Memory and ResourceMonitor->Memory

Answer (score 1):

Is the 4GB combined with two 2GB RAM?
If so, check your RAM slot. Unplug and replug them.

Committed - 2.1/9.9 GB. This is not the actual RAM. This is the actual usable RAM.

[image]